# styled components styled overriden by thrid party (antd) style

Tags: antd, styled-components

I've got a simple styled-components that is being applied to an antd component:

```
import { Card } from 'antd';

export const UsageCard = styled(Card)`

  box-shadow: 1px 1px;
  padding: 2px;
`
```

This creates a div with a class attribute that looks like : "ant-card edit-style__UsageCard-jsklqS hBLsXc ant-card-bordered"

Where .hBLsXc is my styled-component. Unfortunately the padding which is 2px in my styled-componentn gets overriden by the ant-card (0px).

Any idea why this is happening? The styled-components is supposed to come first since it's implemented over the thrid-party component. Is this a problem with the forwarding of className from third-party component I've read on multiple occasion? In any case, I don't really gets how this is supposed to work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `className` has to be put in the Card Component, otherwise this will not work. You should check with `antd` to see if they did so. It has to look something like this:

```
const Card = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    ...
  </div>
)
```

Here is the documentation for it:

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components

edit:
I checked with antd and it looks like you can pass the `className` to it. There is a section in https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/card/index.tsx:

```
const classString = classNames(prefixCls, className, {
      [`${prefixCls}-loading`]: loading,
      [`${prefixCls}-bordered`]: bordered,
      [`${prefixCls}-hoverable`]: this.getCompatibleHoverable(),
      [`${prefixCls}-wider-padding`]: this.state.widerPadding,
      [`${prefixCls}-padding-transition`]: this.updateWiderPaddingCalled,
      [`${prefixCls}-contain-grid`]: this.isContainGrid(),
      [`${prefixCls}-contain-tabs`]: tabList && tabList.length,
      [`${prefixCls}-type-${type}`]: !!type,
    });
```

You can pass the className via props. So this should actually work, but the passed `className` goes first, so I guess the `antd` styles will always override the `styled-components` ones, if they are the same. Maybe a fork might help?

Comment: Yes a fork seem like the right option, but kind of a big deal since I want to stay up to date. I think maybe the best option is to wrap the Card component in a div and override the style .ant-card with normal css. That way it will keep the priority intact.

Comment: Jeah, it totally is. And I would be pretty sure that just changing the order of the classnames will result in a big, not maintainable mess. Better write the component you need from scratch, than trying to forece a ui framework to do something that it was not supposed to do, or be ok with the padding. I think overriding the css classes might be a bad idea and could result in a lot of headaches with overriden classes and stuff. Dont forget to upvote, i like my upvotes ;)